# Are the weights of a linear combination of identifiable Bayesian parameters predicting another variable also identifiable?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, identifiability

Suppose I have a statistical model with observed random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ and Bayesian parameters $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n$ that are identifiable.

Now I want to extend my model by including an observed and non-degenerate random variable $Y$ and parameters $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ in the form

$$Y = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \theta_j.$$

Are the parameters $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ necessarily identifiable?

Comment: I do not understand, $Y$ is an observed random variable, while the $\alpha_j$'s and $\theta_j$'s are parameters???

Comment: What do you mean by “identifiable” here? Could you explain your model? It seems like in your example, you have a single data point $Y$ predicted by a sum of $n$ of $\theta_i$ parameters, this is already not identifiable by the common definition. Then, $2n$ parameters are definitely not identifiable.

Comment: If we for simplicity think of $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n$ as known constants, the additional observation tells you that the linear combitation $\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_j\alpha_j$ of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ must sum to the observed value of $Y$ so the posterior for $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ will be different from the prior so in that sense you learn something about the $\alpha_i$'s from the observed $Y$.  But for a flat improper prior on the $\alpha_i$'s the posterior will also be improper.   So in that sense, the $\alpha_i$'s would not be identifiable.